# Save core data date as a array

Tags: arrays, swift, date, core-data

My swift codes goal is to save a date every time the function is called. What is happening is I am just saving the first date into core data. I assume I need to save it as a array. So that multiple dates and times can be stored. What is being printed is just one date. I want every date printed thanks.

[image]

```
let date = Date()

func enterData() {

    let appDeldeaget = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDeldeaget.persistentContainer.viewContext        
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Data", in: context)
    let theTitle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    theTitle.setValue(date.format(), forKey: "date")

    do {
        try context.save()
        itemName.append(theTitle)
    }
    catch {

    }
    print(date)        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Transformable` type to save an Array.

I've use the same approach to save Dictionaries

[image]

Then you can change `Codegen` to `Manual/None`, click on `Editor`->`Create NSManagedobject Subclass` (top of the screen).

And Xcode will generate `Data` class for you

Comment: And set `Transformer` to `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` to eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your date variable within the function if you want it to be new every time you call the function.

For printing all items, you can use a loop:

```
do {
    try context.save()
    items.append(theTitle)
}
catch {
} 
for item in items {
    print(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do that is to create a different table called dates that has a relationship **1 to many** with your table.

That **Dates** table will have 3 fields (ownerID, date, order)
So you can just add one row in the table to add one date for the object that you want to implement a date in the array.

After for your Table you can fetch all the dates that have the same ownerID ordered by order and create your custom array.